# which kinds of lubricant / grease can attack carbon fibre components and which kinds cause no harm or damage?

Tags: materials, carbon-fiber

It's easy to find many non-expert opinions about the dangers of using grease on carbon fibre components. Which kinds of lubricant cause no harm to carbon components, and which, if any, can damage them?

Comment: Not an expert on this, but I would guess it is the resin, more so than the carbon, that is vulnerable.

Comment: @Pete W:  Thanks. I've edited the question title.

Comment: Silicone grease is typically inert and is suitable for most materials, besides silicone rubber. I'm also not an expert.